# What is this tree with purple flowers?

Tags: identification

This is growing in our garden in Melbourne, Australia and was here when we moved in.

[image: purple flowering tree]

It has these lovely purple flowers in summer and is around 2.5m tall.

It seems to be thriving but it would be nice to know how to care for it.

Comment: The ones I see in Melbourne are uncared-for. I fertilise and irrigate one lucky tree, it is perhaps a little leafier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a *Tibouchina*, a member of the family Melastomataceae. An attractive, hardy shrub native to South America, but commonly grown in Australia where they do well in most regions.
There are numerous species and countless cultivars, so I cannot tell exactly which one you have, but here is a [fact sheet](http://www.abc.net.au/gardening/stories/s2040246.htm) on their general care and cultivation.

Comment: From looking at photos of different varieties it seems very much like Tibouchina urvilleana 'Edwardsii'